# Android - ImageView exact coordinates

Tags: android-imageview

how can I get the exact coordinates of a point in imageview?
Just think my image is a bitmap of map of a city and it's width is greater that screen and it is in a scrollview.

I want to take the same x and y values for same place on image after scrolling? How can I calculate these? Math calculations is not a problem but I couldn't find which data(property) I have to use.